# Can't locate Net/IP.pm

Tags: perl

I've successfully installed `NetAddr` via this: `cpan -i NetAddr::DNS`

Now I'm trying to launch this basic program:

```
use Net::IP;

my $ip = new Net::IP ('193.0.1/24') or die (Net::IP::Error());
print ("IP  : ".$ip->ip()."\n");
print ("Sho : ".$ip->short()."\n");
print ("Bin : ".$ip->binip()."\n");
print ("Int : ".$ip->intip()."\n");
print ("Mask: ".$ip->mask()."\n");
print ("Last: ".$ip->last_ip()."\n");
print ("Len : ".$ip->prefixlen()."\n");
print ("Size: ".$ip->size()."\n");
print ("Type: ".$ip->iptype()."\n");
print ("Rev:  ".$ip->reverse_ip()."\n");
```

But I get:

```
rr@sd-562 # perl tmp.pl
Can't locate Net/IP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at tmp.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tmp.pl line 1.
rr@sd-562 # updatedb
rr@sd-562 # locate IP.pm
/root/.cpan/build/NetAddr-IP-4.071-YZOO46/IP.pm
/root/.cpan/build/NetAddr-IP-4.071-YZOO46/blib/lib/NetAddr/IP.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/NetAddr/IP.pm
```

And I haven't found something valuable on the Web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Net::IP and NetAddr::IP are different modules. They have different names.

Answer (score 5):

- Can’t locate NetAddr/IP.pm in @INC --> sudo apt-get install libnet-ip-perl
- Can’t locate Net/Netmask.pm in @INC --> sudo apt-get install libnet-netmask-perl
- Can’t locate Net/DNS.pm in @INC --> sudo apt-get install libnet-dns-perl
- Can’t locate XML/Writer.pm in @INC --> sudo apt-get install libxml-writer-perl

Answer (score 0):

This article worked for me:
ref: https://www.angellight.com/knowledgebase/1581/REQUIRED-module-missing-NetAddr-IP.html

If you get the error:
Can't locate NetAddr/IP.pm in @INC

then run:
wget http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/NetAddr/NetAddr-IP-4.078.tar.gz
tar xvzf NetAddr-IP-4.078.tar.gz
cd NetAddr-IP-4.078
perl Makefile.PL
make
make install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).